# Requests.get UnicodeDecodeError 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests

I'm trying to use `requests.get` in Python (3.9.1) but with some URLs I'm getting encoding errors:

```
url = 'http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?icep_ff3=9&icep_uq=+ul3135+siliconerubberwirecable10/12/18/20awg30awg200%C2%B0c'
r = requests.get(url)
print (r.status_code)
```

and the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\D\Code\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "sessions.py", line 677, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "sessions.py", line 677, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "sessions.py", line 237, in resolve_redirects
    resp = self.send(
  File "sessions.py", line 692, in send
    r._next = next(self.resolve_redirects(r, request, yield_requests=True, **kwargs))
  File "sessions.py", line 150, in resolve_redirects
    url = self.get_redirect_target(resp)
  File "sessions.py", line 116, in get_redirect_target
    return to_native_string(location, 'utf8')
  File "_internal_utils.py", line 25, in to_native_string
    out = string.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 85: invalid start byte
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here, the content that requests is getting from the URL or the actual URL string? By changing a few numbers in the URL, the error magically goes away while for this exact URL the error is present.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The `requests` module is very powerful because it automatically handles a number of HTTP things like redirections. But this comes at the price of some *magic* and when things go wrong, it is harder to exactly know where.

I had to guess here. Your url contains the sequence `%C2%B0`. This is the urlencoded value for the Unicode character DEGREE SIGN `°` (code 0xB0) in utf8 charset (`b'\xc2\xb0'`). And it is the character that causes the error...

The HTTP protocol has no provision to declare an encoding in the URL itself. You can only declare an encoding for the body (or the headers), and it is recommended to only use ISO-8859-1 (AKA Latin1) encoding in the URL.

So the solution is to use the Latin1 charset and use `'...awg200%B0c'`. It works, but only `requests` experts could explain why... (and I am not one of them!)

I do not know where the URL come from but it is likely to be produced with something like `urllib.parse.quote(...)`. You must use an explicit Latin1 encoding:

```
url = urllib.parse.quote_from_bytes('...'.encode('Latin1'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this sollution. I tried encoding the url string before requests.get like so `url = urllib.parse.quote_from_bytes(url.encode('Latin1'))` but I'm getting errors `"requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'http%3A//rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1%3Ficep_ff3%3D9%26icep_uq%3D%2Bul3135%2Bsiliconerubberwirecable10/12/18/20awg30awg200%25C2%25B0c'"`

Comment: @FlorinC.: You have encoded the `:` in `http://` hence the error. You should only only encode the query part. I could give better advices if you showed how you composed the original url.

Comment: I am not composing them, I have text file with these URLs in JSON format. I'm loading the file and going through each url in the list `json.load(data_file)`

Comment: @FlorinC.: does the JSON file contains the `%C2%B0` part?

Comment: @FlorinC. : then it will be hard to build a simple yet general fix: either you fully split the query and process separately each key and value of the query part, or you must take care of not converting the *real* `?`, `&` and `=` characters.

Comment: This answer was useful to read the html response of a request.

Using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 solved the following classical error message:


`>>> txt = r.content.decode('UTF-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 35078: invalid continuation byte`


Instead, using the following line didn't throw the error:
`>>> txt = r.content.decode('ISO-8859-1')`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue,
Here is how I solved the problem.

The url casing the error had a numbers next to a slash
e.g
.../numbers

So I remade the url like this (used back-slash before the slash)
.../numbers

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar error on a url from one of the popular url shortening websites.  I ended up using the `urllib` library.

```py
import requests
import urllib

try:
    rs = requests.get(url)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    resolved_url = urllib.request.urlopen(url).geturl()
    rs = requests.get(resolved_url)
```

This is clearly inefficient as `urlopen` is doing a lot of extra work but it has worked well as a fallback.

Used `python 3.8.10` and `requests 2.26.0`